# iPad navigation automatically imposes slideout

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a NavigationView with three NavigationLinks, on portrait iPhone, it works as expected where one taps a link, a new view is presented with a Back button. However on an iPad in landscape (which this app is designed for only), iOS forces a slideout menu from the left side instead of showing the three links on the view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView()) {
                    Text("Item 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewC()) {
                    Text("Item 2")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentViewB()) {
                    Text("Item 3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions for overriding this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this issue by adding this

`.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`

to your `NavigationView`

```
NavigationView {
            ...
}.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

This will force it to render a standard stack (like you see on the phone) rather than defaulting to the split view layout.